# Python: Count Number of Element-Wise Equal Elements

Tags: python

I want to count the number of times two lists (`list1` and `list2`) have the same number in the same index.

First, there's this approach:

```
def count_common(list1, list2):
    count = 0
    for i, elem1 in enumerate(list1):
        if elem1 == list2[i]:
            count += 1
    return count
```

This is O(n) time and O(1) space.

If I try the more Pythonic way, I get O(n) space:

```
def count_common(list1, list2):
    return sum([1 for (elem1, elem2) in zip(list1, list2) if elem1 == elem2])
```

Is there a Pythonic way of doing it that maintains the O(1) space used in my initial solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should really understand that using one-liners is **not synonymous with Pythonic**. That being said, you can use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension to use constant space:

```
sum(a == b for a, b in zip(list1, list2))
```

I would actually use the above one-liner. It is very readable. However, the equivalent for loop is *just as fine*:

```
total = 0
for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
    total += a == b
```

Indeed, I wouldn't be surprised if the for loop approach is more performant. You lose a lot to generator overhead.